# How to remove warning notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

Code has implementation of `notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock` and it is giving warning as it is deprecated.

I have added new method `notifyWhenInteractionChangesUsingBlock` and
removed deprecated method then another warning pops up that

Class does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator'.
Add stubs for missing protocol requirements.

If I click on fix button then it implements deprecated method again.

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be declaring conformance to UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator. You are not the coordinator. The coordinator is the coordinator. You are the view controller. `notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock` is not something you implement; it is something you call. Although to be honest I have never found a reason to call it.

Perhaps you meant UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate ?

Or UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning ?

Or both ?

Comment: I have added this method in the code still it gives me same warning. I will update my post here.

Comment: You should not be adding it at all.